# GridSplitter like for listview: Is there any such control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview that I want to give the user the chance to resize the height of items similar to a gridsplitter. Is there any such control for this purpose?

I am using wpf and .net 4.5, c#

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a canvas with two listviews, and then use a thumb control to allow you to resize those listviews.

Thumb control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but can get you started: http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2008/05/06/wpf-listviewgridview-minimum-and-maximum-width-for-a-column.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use `DataGrid` and set its `RowHeaderWidth` to the desired value to make the splitter area more visible to user.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to put an object into a raw similar to what I can do with a listview. Is there a way to template a grid to be able to have only one column in each row and the column width be always the width of datagrid? a way to mimic listview using a datagrid?

Comment: if you set RowHeaderTemplate and bind RowHeaderWidth to ActualWidth of DataGrid and also remove all columns from grid, then yes.